# Java Android - Get an Image from a webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

So I load a page of a website and its show on my android APP via webview.

The website have several images on it; let's say the website page contains 3 images:

```
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg">
<img src="random_image.php">
<img src="pic_mountain_second.jpg">
```

my question is, how do I get each of the images above, so I can access each of it as Bitmap on my Java Android apps?

Comment: do you have images complete web path?

Comment: You just want to show the image on webview?

Comment: @SohailZahid yes, the image complete web path is: https://sapsnkra.moe.gov.my/randomimage.php

Comment: @PreetikaKaur no, I want to get the captcha image, and solve in using another API...

so, if I load the page in webview, it will gave me a captcha images...so how to get exactly the same captcha image so I can send it to another API and solve it. Because if I do another image request to that url, it will send a different captcha image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example to get HTML as string which is loaded in webview and how you can get image url from that after you can convert image url to bitmap.

set webview client to your webview like

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebClientClass());
```

The webview client is given below

```
public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            wvAboutUs.evaluateJavascript(
                    "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
                    new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(html));
                            reader.setLenient(true);
                            try {
                                if (reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                                    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                                        String msg = reader.nextString();
                                        if (msg != null) {
                                            Log.d("HTML", msg);
                                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
                                            Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);
                                            if (m.find()) {
                                                Log.d("HTML", m.group(1)); // This will print your image url
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e("TAG", "MainActivity: IOException", e);
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    reader.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.
I have 2 questions:
1. what is "wvAboutUs"?
2. since <img src="random_image.php"> is always generate random images every time I called it, so when I called using above method, there's a possibility that the result will be different then the one in my webview, is it correct? because I saw that above method will call another image on random_image.php. 

Thanks!